# О запятой: Названы женские профессии

Tags: пунктуация

Названы женские профессии, виновные в разводах. Запятая нужна, правда ведь?

Answer (score 5):

**Названы женские профессии, "виновные" в разводах.**

Запятая нужна (определительный оборот после определяемого слова), но прилагательное "виновные" хорошо бы заключить в кавычки: в разводах виноваты люди определенных профессий, а не сами профессии.

Comment: ок, спасибо, поставила)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая-то нужна, так как словосочетание стоит после определяемого слова "профессия". Можно и так: *"Названы виновные в разводах женские профессии"*, - но я сильно сомневаюсь, могут ли быть **профессии** виновными!
Виновный - совершивший преступное, предосудительное; тот, на **ком** лежит вина. То есть о профессии так не скажешь.
Хорошо заменить на "являющиеся причинами разводов" или как-то так.